# How do I connect to OAuth in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

For a project I am trying to create a consumer role that does not utilise tokens.

I have managed to create the required details in the code-behind:

```
        string outUrl = "";
    string querystring = "";

    string consumerKey = "";
    string consumerSecret = "";
    Uri uri = new Uri("");

    oAuthBase2 oAuth = new oAuthBase2();
    string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
    string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();

    string sig = oAuth.GenerateSignature(uri, consumerKey, consumerSecret, string.Empty, string.Empty,
        "POST", timeStamp, nonce, oAuthBase2.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out outUrl,
        out querystring);
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Why are you trying *not* to use Tokens? Tokens are the only way relate who the request is from on subsequent handshakes.

Comment: OK, I am starting to build up an understanding. Basically, I am trying to utilise a 2 legged oauth approach using devdefined oauth like this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032873/has-anybody-implemented-2-legged-oauth-using-dnoa) but the data needs to include a userID with the data to be signed. For the life of me cannot work out how to sign it with the extra parameter

Comment: DNOA allows you to put things in the `ExtraData[]` parameter. I don't know whether DevDefined does or not. Why are you constrained to DevDefined?

Comment: because on utilisation the user is redirected to the external source and their demands as per LTI standards.

Comment: So their site says you *must* use a specific OAuth Library? Mind. Blown.

Answer (score 3):

Your first stop should be the [OAuth specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849). It explains exactly what each step is for.  If you want an OAuth example using [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) (easily the most complete OAuth library for .NET), I've [included one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799323/how-do-i-use-oauth-to-connect-to-the-etrade-api/7904228#7904228).

The DotNetOpenAuth source code also contains examples for connecting to Facebook, Twitter, and Google.

Answer (score 2):

DOtNetOpenAuth is overly complicated and does not help a beginner to understand the OAuth dialog. For a small project using OAuth on the client side, let me suggest [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) which is simple, not the best, but at least you know what you're doing. [Here is a sample of code to get you started](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs). I hope this helps !